# Jquery prop() returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery and trying to make a http request so that I don't have to leave the current page, but

```
var getURL = $("#callerId").attr("href");
```

does not seem to be working
console.log(getURL) displays "undefined"

there's the source code (everything down to callerId should be correct)

```
    <script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.hrefURL a').click(function(dontRedirect) {
        dontRedirect.preventDefault(); 
        var callerId = event.target.id;
        var getURL = $("#callerId").attr("href");
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url: getURL,
            success: function(response){
                alert($('#response'));  
            }
        });

    });
});

</script>


<a href="javascript:document.location = TTS1" id = "1T">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
var getURL = $(this).attr("href");
```

instead of

```
var getURL = $("#callerId").attr("href");
```

In the first case `$(this)` points to the jquery object of the anchor you just clicked, in the second - it points to some element that isn't even covered by your example

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/YJRLR/

Comment: Kind of silly to do `$(this).attr("href");` when `this.href` is shorter and faster.  jQuery should only be used when it's a better way to do something.

Comment: @jfriend00: indeed, but from another point of view - OP now knows of `$(this)` presence

Comment: I just figure you should NEVER teach a newbie the wrong way to do something.  You could have shown them both how to use `this.href` and how to use `$(this)` like I did in my answer.

Comment: @jfriend00: "wrong way" - you're overdramatizing. Not that efficient - yes, wrong - nope

Comment: Well, it's certainly not the best way.  When teaching someone how to use jQuery, I feel like we have a responsibility to teach them efficient and appropriate techniques and that includes when it's appropriate to use jQuery and when plain JS is better.  For kicks, the OP could use this:  `$("#" + $(e.target.id).attr("id")).attr("href")` if they wanted.

Comment: @jfriend00: super-otimization and super-efficient practices make sense when other code is perfect as well. For newbies it makes no sense, because one `this.href` instead of `$(this)...` changes nothing. The first thing newbies need to learn how to do - is to write a code that at least works as expected. And only after that learn how to write it efficiently.

Comment: When to use jQuery and when not to use jQuery is part of the first things one should learn when learning jQuery.  Otherwise, you just learn how to do things inefficiently from the start and never learn the efficient way.  Apparently you think they should learn the inefficient way first - I have a different opinion on that.  Once most programmers learn something that works, they tend to just go on using it and learning other new things.  Why not learn it the best way the first time?

Comment: @jfriend00: "Apparently you think they should learn the inefficient way first" --- I don't. As I said - they need to learn how to write **working** code, regardless its efficiency. "Why not learn it the best way the first time?" --- because they don't understand the difference yet. Blind following advices without understanding **why** doing this way not another is evil as well.

Comment: Except `$(this).attr("href")` is never the desirable way to do it and that's what you taught them.  OK, we can agree to disagree, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to be doing this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.hrefURL a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        var getURL = this.href;
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url: getURL,
            success: function(response){
                alert($('#response'));  
            }
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

Things to know about your previous code:

1. `this` will be automatically set to the object that caused the event so you don't have to get `target.id`.
2. You can get the value of href with `this.href`.  There is no need to use jQuery for that.
3. If you wanted to make the value of `this` into a jQuery object, you would do it with `$(this)` or with `$(e.target.id)`.  You use strings with jQuery when it's a CSS selector.  You use variable values directly when you already have the object reference.